# Return incorrect time when call API in spring boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, datetime, time

my mapping code here:

```
@Column(name = "movie_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String name;

@Column(name = "director", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String director;

@Column(name = "cast", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String cast;

@Column(name = "duration_start", nullable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Asia/Vietnam")
private Date durationStart;

@Column(name = "duration_end", nullable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date durationEnd;

@Column(name = "genre", nullable = false)
private String genre;

@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "release_date", nullable = false, length = 50)
private Date releaseDate;

@Column(name = "language", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String language;

@Column(name = "rated", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String rate;

@Column(name = "poster", length = 1000, nullable =  false)
private String poster;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
private List<Ticket> listTickets;
```

}`

i have data time like that image:[image]

but when i call api it return like here :[image]it is seem that the time is automatically plus 8 hours when i call api (int duration_start)

i am trying to add annotation @jsonformat and fix server utc in application.properpties but it is seem that it is not effective

Comment: That’s what happens when you try to misuse a `Date` for a duration. It’s taken to be a time of day and gets adjusted for UTC offset.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the time zone is inconsistent with the spring json constructor you are using. First, you can print the time obtained by the backend to see if it is the same as the frontend. If not, you need to configure the springboot file.
add content:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    time-zone: (Your Timezone)
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

If the two are consistent, you need to check whether the time stored in the database is the same as the correct time. If there is a gap between the time of the database and the actual time, you need to edit the file in the spring database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://11.1.1.1111:3306/database?characterEncoding=utf-8&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
```

Database configuration followed by

```
 &serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
```

("%2B" means "+","%2D" means "-",choose your Timezone)

You can also check whether the time zone of the database is correct. If not, you can set the database time zone (but not recommended, it will affect the old data)

```
set global time_zone = '+7:00';

set time_zone = '+7:00';
```

Or add it in springboot's application.properties

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.time-zone= GMT+7
```

Comment: I just realized that the time is only incorrect when i mapped by @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) if i set @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) it does not make a mistake. why?

Comment: the above thing i said,  only fix  getmapping. when i call postmapping,  in database automatically still plus 11 hours:((

Comment: The return value of the interface method annotated with @RestController or @Controller+@ResponseBody in spring-boot is in Json format by default.

So when the data of date type is returned, it will be converted by the default Jackson framework of spring-boot, and the default time zone of the Jackson framework is GMT.   I modified my answer, there is a modification method of the relevant configuration file, you can try to modify it

Comment: thanks bro. i solved that. I actually marked annotation @creationtimestamp for time type and date type as redundant